# How to get AutoIt Info for msctls_progress32

Tags: progress-bar, ui-automation, autoit

I am attempting to automate the configuration of a Third Party Windows application.

During the process a progress bar regularly appears which I need to wait for, e.g. wait for it to disappear.

While I can successfully obtain a handle for the progress bar with this code

```
; Retrieve the handle of the progess bar
Local $hProgressBar = ControlGetHandle($MainWindow, "", "[CLASS:msctls_progress32; INSTANCE:1]")
```

I am not able to wait while it is visible

I have tried

```
WinWaitNotActive($MainWindow, "Save Changes")
```

And

```
Local $isProgressVisible = ControlCommand($MainWindow, "", $hProgressBar, "IsVisible")

While $isProgressVisible
    Sleep($iSleepy)
    $isProgressVisible = ControlCommand($MainWindow, "", $hProgressBar, "IsVisible")
WEnd
```

Neither of these approaches makes my script wait.

When I attempt to use the AutoIt Info tool to retrieve the progress bars details
it breaks/stops my script and gives no info at all.

Is there an AutoIt function I can use to obtain the progress bars details?

Comment: What is the app? I might be able to get the infos au3 info tools fails to get but I need to test it.

Comment: the application is the windows management console for IBM® InfoSphere® Change Data Capture